# cases environment inside an array

Tags: errors, lyx, arrays, cases

LyX is giving a lot of error messages for my Latex code which runs in other places.

```
\[
\begin{array}{rl}
p_{Y \mid H_1}(y \mid H_1) & = f_X(g^{-1}(y))\left| \dfrac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy} \right| \\ \\
& = \begin{cases} y>0 & : & f_X(\ln(y))\left| \dfrac{d \ln(y)}{dy} \right| = \dfrac{f_X(\ln(y))}{y} \\
\text{otherwise} & : & 0
\end{cases}
\end{array}
\]
```

LyX says:

```
Extra alignment tabs changed to \cr.
 & = \begin{cases} y>0 & : &
                                  f_X(\ln(y))\left| \dfrac{d \ln(y)}{dy} \ri...
You have given more \span or & marks than there were
in the preamble to the \halign or \valign now in progress.
So I'll assume that you meant to type \cr instead.
```

However the exact code works perfectly in the [SE Mathematics domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to give this output:

[image: should have been like this]

What does LyX not like in my code?

Comment: The difference is that Lyx uses TeX to do the typesetting and MathJax as used on the math site does not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a solution which (a) uses the `align*` environment instead of the `array` environment and (b) inverts the order of the arguments inside the `cases` environment (as I believe that this may be closer to general usage of this environment). It also defines a macro called `\abs` to simplify typesetting in the body of the example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left|#1\right|}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
p_{Y \mid H_1}(y \mid H_1) 
&= f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \abs{ \dfrac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy} } \\ 
&= \begin{cases}
      f_X(\ln(y)) \abs{ \dfrac{d \ln(y)}{dy} } = \dfrac{f_X(\ln(y))}{y} & \text{if $y>0$}\\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to state the condition part before the result part in the `cases` environment, you could write it as:

```
   \begin{cases}
      \text{if $y>0$} &:\  
        f_X(\ln(y)) \abs{ \dfrac{d \ln(y)}{dy} } = \dfrac{f_X(\ln(y))}{y}\\
      \text{otherwise} &:\ 0  
   \end{cases}
```

leading to the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

`cases` only takes one alignment point (that is, it is a two column table) and you have used two on each row. Deleting the extra ones makes it work. Please in future always post *complete* documents showing all relevant packages (amsmath here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{rl}
p_{Y \mid H_1}(y \mid H_1) & = f_X(g^{-1}(y))\left| \dfrac{dg^{-1}(y)}{dy} \right| \\ \\
& = \begin{cases} y>0  : & f_X(\ln(y))\left| \dfrac{d \ln(y)}{dy} \right| = \dfrac{f_X(\ln(y))}{y} \\
\text{otherwise}  : & 0
\end{cases}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

While this works it is misusing `array` (which intended for matrices not as an aligned display) You would be better to use the ams alignments such as `align`.